# how to deal with time zone when it comes to using neural prophet?

Tags: pandas, deep-learning, duplicates, timezone-offset, facebook-prophet

I have data with a timestep of 1 min for almost a year and a half. I removed the timezone from the timestamp, now the format looks like this: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss". Then I renamed the time column to "ds" and the target to "y" so that it would work with neural prophet. It gives me the following error: (**Column ds has duplicate values. Please remove duplicates.**) . And this is because of the time-change throughout the year, it's like there is a whole duplicated hour with 1 min resolution. It's a 60 data points, I thought of deleting them, but is there any other way around it?
Note: I used Prophet before and I didn't face this problem.
Thanks

Comment: How do you remove the timezone? Please provide a sample of your data before removing TZ.

Comment: Before removing the timezone, the data would look like: 2021-11-07 01:47:00-07:00, which is GMT-7 timezone. This is my code for removing the time zone:

Comment: import datetime as dt from datetime  
import datetime from dateutil.tz import tzoffset  
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])  df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(tzinfo=None))  Then the data com out like this: 2021-11-07 01:47:00

Answer (score 0):

You should not remove the timezone with `replace(tzinfo=None)` because you don't remove the duplicate values due to DST. You have to use `tz_convert`:

Try:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.tz_convert(None)
```

Output:

```
# Before
>>> df
                        Time
0  2021-11-07 01:47:00-07:00

# After
>>> df
                 Time
0 2021-11-07 08:47:00
```

Comment: Got this error: AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values. I loaded my data with this command: pd.read_csv() I didn't add parse because then it will use the timestamp column for indexing and I won't be able to do df['Time']